# XSD schema abstract type problem

Tags: xsd

I have a problem with an xsd schema file.

I have this abstract complex type on my schema:

```
<complexType name="Action" abstract="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="actionType">
            <complexType>
                <choice>
                    <element name="ALARMACTION"/>
                    <element name="REPORTDATAACTION"/>
                    <element name="ENABLEOBSERVATIONACTION"/>
                    <element name="DISABLEOBSERVATIONACTION"/>
                    <element name="SETOBSERVATIONSCHEDULEACTION"/>
            <element name="VERIFYOVERTIMEACTION"/>
                </choice>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

This is a concrete implementation of Action abstract element:

```
<complexType name="AlarmAction">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ref:Action">
            <sequence>
                <element name="alarmCode" type="integer"/>
                <element name="report" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

This element references the abstract Action element:

```
<complexType name="Conclusion">
    <sequence>
        <element minOccurs="0" name="observationSet" type="ref:ObservationSet"/>
        <element name="action" type="ref:Action"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

I got an error with this xml instance:

```
            <Conclusion>
                <observationSet>
                    <observationPhenomenum>HIGH_HEARTBEAT</observationPhenomenum>
                </observationSet>
                <action>
                    <actionType>
                        <ENABLEOBSERVATIONACTION></ENABLEOBSERVATIONACTION>
                    </actionType>
                <observationId>1</observationId>
                <observationId>2</observationId>
                </action>
        </Conclusion>
```

The error on netbeans is this: cvc-type.2: The type definition cannot be abstract for element action. [104]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an abstract complexType as element type, but the user writing a XML instance document with this schema has to state the type of the element.

For your example this means you have to write it as follows:

```
<Conclusion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="conclusion.xsd">
  <observationSet>
    <observationPhenomenum>HIGH_HEARTBEAT</observationPhenomenum>
  </observationSet>
  <action xsi:type="AlarmAction">
    <actionType>
      <ENABLEOBSERVATIONACTION></ENABLEOBSERVATIONACTION>
    </actionType>
    <alarmCode>10</alarmCode>
    <report>Whatever</report>
  </action>
</Conclusion>
```

For more information hav a look here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wci/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.cast_iron.doc%2Fmap_Selecting_a_Substitution_Type.html

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the schema is valid; you do have somewhere a definition for a global element with the local name "Conclusion", and a non-abstract, complex type deriving from Action, with repeating **observationId** elements (e.g. ***XYZAction***).

Your problem then is rezolved if you add **xsi:type="*XYZAction*"** as an attribute to your **action** element. Again, the attribute value must match the name of a non-abstract type, that derives from the abstract Action.

My advice to you is when in doubt, use a tool to generate a sample XML for the scenario you have in mind. I am using [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com), since it allows me to easily build any scenario imaginable using simple drag and drop of XML Schema elements.

Answer (score 0):

While validation of request xml against wsdl you have to include following attributes

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" use this in the root element 

on abstract type element 

<abstractElement name="XYZ" xsi:type="Name of your instance" > </abstractElement>
```